# Use CreateView and ListView in the same template and use form.instance correctly

Tags: python, django

In my project my user should be able to submit an appointment (class `UserAppointment`) based on the responsibility given by the staff (class `StaffDuty`). So I'd like to use the `CreateView` class of the `UserAppointment` model and `ListView` class for the `StaffDuty` model in the same template. With my code I can access the data from the `StaffDuty` model but I'm not able to submit the form for `UserAppointment` model, since the submit button does nothing.

Also I'd like to automatically assign the staff and event foreign key and pass data from `StaffDuty` to complete `form.instance.date_appointment` with the date given in the staff model and `form.instance.event_name` with the name of the event that is found in the `Event` model. But my code is not working at all

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    staff_needed = models.PositiveIntegerField()    
    date = models.DateField()   
    spots_total = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('event_details', args=[str(self.id)])


class StaffDuty(models.Model):             
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_work = models.DateField()  
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event.name | str(self.date_work) 


class UserAppointment(models.Model):            
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(StaffDuty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_appointment = models.DateField(null=True)  
    morning_hour = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    afternoon_hour = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    spots_free = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event.name | str(self.staff.date_work)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**views.py**

```
class StaffDutyAddView(CreateView):
    model = StaffDuty
    form_class = StaffDutyForm
    template_name = 'reservation.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class UserAppointmentAddView(CreateView):
    model = UserAppointment
    form_class = UserAppointmentForm
    template_name = "reservation.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user.userinformation
        # Code incomplete and that not work 
        form.instance.staff = StaffDuty.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.staffduty).first()
        #form.instance.date_appointment = # add date_work from StaffDuty class
        form.instance.event = Event.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.event).first()
        #form.instance.event_name = # add name of the event from Event class
        return super(UserAppointmentAddView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = StaffDuty.objects.order_by('id')
        return super(UserAppointmentAddView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**html**

```
                           <div class="container">

                               {% for appointment in object_list %}
                               <tbody>
                                   <tr class="inner-box">
                                       <th scope="row">
                                           <div class="event-date">                                                                                                            
                                           </div>
                                       </th>
                                       <td>
                                           <div class="event-img">
                                               {% if appointment.id_image %}
                                               <img src="#" alt="">
                                               {% endif %}
                                               <p>{{ appointment.event}}</p> 
                                           </div>
                                       </td>
                                       <td>                                            
                                           <div class="event-wrap">
                                               <h3><a href="#">{{ appointment.get_shift_display }}</a></h3>                                                
                                                   <div class="time">
                                                       <span>{{ form.staff }}</span>
                                                       <span>{{ form.event }}</span>
                                                       <span>{{ form.morning_hour }}</span>
                                                       <span>{{ form.afternoon_hour }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                           <div class="r-no">
                                               <span> {{ appointment.spots_free }}/{{ appointment.event.spots_total }}</span>
                                           </div>
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                           <div class="r-no">
                                               <span>{{ appointment.event.venue }}</span>
                                           </div>
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                           <div class="primary-btn">
                                               <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                           </div>
                                       </td>
                                   </tr>
                            </tbody>      
{% endfor %}
```

P.s (I had to change my code a little to make it shorter and more clear. They may be typo that are not in my original code)

Comment: There is no form to submit in your HTML file. Did you accidentally delete it while you're changing your code for posting here?

Comment: Can you refactor this question to make it more concise? Your submit button does nothing because it's not within a `<form>`. What data is there to submit?